# Travis CI loading private submodule

Tags: travis-ci, git-submodules

At the moment I'm troubling with Travis-CI Pro and a private submodule.

This is some travis.yml code I've found, the $GIT_USER and $GIT_TOKEN envs are set in travis settings.

```
git:
  submodules: false
before_install:
  - sed -i 's/git@github.com:/https:\/\/$GIT_USER:$GIT_TOKEN@github.com\//' .gitmodules
  - git submodule update --init --recursive
```

During the build process I get the following error:

```
$ sed -i 's/git@github.com:/https:\/\/$GIT_USER:$GIT_TOKEN@github.com\//' .gitmodules
0.67s$ git submodule update --init --recursive
Submodule 'ro-realm' (https://github.com/[secure]/ro-realm.git) registered for path 'ro-realm'
Cloning into '/home/travis/build/[secure]/ro-order-worker/ro-realm'...
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/[secure]/ro-realm.git/'
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: depends on what $GIT_USER and GIT_TOKEN are. any chance they those vars have the bad characters in them, causing them not to be imported correctly?

Comment: No, I copied them and proved them twice, they are definetly correct.

Comment: I tried to set the git username and the token directly into the code snippet (bad practice, I know), but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call this a recommended solution, but how about this to fix the issue?

```
# Generate from github, confirm that user and token are correct
echo https://${GIT_USER}:${GIT_TOKEN}@github.com/chaconinc/DbConnector
git submodule add https://${GIT_USER}:${GIT_TOKEN}@github.com/chaconinc/DbConnector
git submodule update --init --recursive
```